# what is the linkshare used in a website application

Tags: session, jakarta-ee

```
session.setAttribute("referrer", "linkshare");
```

This is how it is mentioned in some code.
    How does this work??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this just sets an Object in the session ...( that is the scope of the variable is maintained for that session )

syntax : session.setAttribute(attributeName,attributeValue);

while getting (ObjectType)session.getAttribute(attributeName);

for example setting and getting an object of type string

```
HttpSession session=request.getSession();
String name="abc";
session.setAttribute("nameSession",name);
String sname = (String)session.getAttribute(name);
```